# Calling a module function inside a Nodejs callback

Tags: node.js, casperjs

I have a module that writes to a log file. (coffeescript sorry, but you get the idea!)

```
require = patchRequire(global.require)
fs = require('fs')

exports.h =

  log: ()->
    for s in arguments
      fs.appendFile "log.txt", "#{s}\n", (e)->
        if (e) then throw e
```

It works file when I call it directly.  But when I call it from a callback, for example  casperjs start event:

```
h = require('./h').h
casper = require('casper').create()

casper.start "http://google.com", ()->
  h.log("hi")

casper.run()
```

... I always get this or similar "undefined" TyepError:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'fs.appendFile("log.txt", "" + s + "\n", function(e) {
      if (e) {
        throw e;
      }
    })')
```

Googling this doesn't give many clues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CasperJS runs on PhantomJS (or SlimerJS) and uses its modules. It is distinct from nodejs. PhantomJS' [fs module](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) doesn't have an `appendFile` function.

Of course you can use `fs.write(filepath, content, 'a');` to append to a file if used in casper. If you still want to use your module both in casper and node then you need to write some glue code like

```
function append(file, content, callback) {
    if (fs.appendFile) {
        fs.appendFile(file, content, callback);
    } else {
        fs.write(file, content, 'a');
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. It's really useful to know that casperjs runs on PhantomJS and not nodejs, it's not obvious that the fs module is different for newcomers but it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the coffeescript.  Try using a splat parameter instead of relying on the arguments object.

`log(statements...)`

If that doesn't work, you might need to look at the javascript output or try the same thing in plain JavaScript and see if you get the same error.